# Add variable to melt function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my input, question is below:

```
Targets <- read.csv("miR155Aicda.csv", row.names=1, sep="", header=T)          
head(Targets)

               T0h T0.25h T0.5h  T1h  T2h  T3h  T6h T12h T24h T48h C0h C0.25h C0.5h C1h  C2h
Aicda          785   1150   707  513 1265 3268 8294 8625 7387 4397 677    911   673 737 1782
mmu-miR-155-3p 622    548   558 1213 1195 1172 1115 1883 3257 1900 499    562   584 543  580

Targets.m <- melt(Targets)
> head(Targets.m)
  variable     value
1      T0h  9.616549
2      T0h  9.280771
3   T0.25h 10.167418
4   T0.25h  9.098032
5    T0.5h  9.465566
6    T0.5h  9.124121
```

Question: How do I add `Aicda` and `mmu-mIR-155-2p` as a variable?

I want this:

```
      ID                variable     value
1   Aicda                  T0h    9.616549
2   mmu-miR-155-3p        T0h     9.280771
3   Aicda                  T0.25h 10.167418
4   mmu-miR-155-3p          T0.25h  9.098032
5   Aicda                  T0.5h   9.465566
6  mmu-miR-155-3p          T0.5h  9.124121
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the rownames in a column and then specify an id variable for `melt`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="               T0h T0.25h T0.5h  T1h  T2h  T3h  T6h T12h T24h T48h C0h C0.25h C0.5h C1h  C2h
Aicda          785   1150   707  513 1265 3268 8294 8625 7387 4397 677    911   673 737 1782
mmu-miR-155-3p 622    548   558 1213 1195 1172 1115 1883 3257 1900 499    562   584 543  580",header=TRUE)

DF$ID <- rownames(DF)
library(reshape2)
melt(DF,id="ID")
```

Comment: Instead of adding the ID column to the `data.frame`, here's a possible alternative: `cbind(ID = rownames(DF), melt(DF))`